# How to include a custom php file?

Tags: php, symfony

I have added a new directory and a new file into `src/AppBundle`. So the path is: `src/AppBundle/Helper/Helper.php`

The path of my controller is as usual `src/AppBundle/Controller/MyController.php`.

I would now like to include the file `Helper.php` to my Controller. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you use any namespace?

Comment: @ChinLeung yes, I do.

Comment: Do you have an autoloader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility,  assuming your `AppBundle/Controller/MyController` in Symfony 2.8 it looks something like this:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller\MyController

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class MyController extends Controller
{
...
}
```

and your Helper class includes `public function getSomeHelp()`

you can then define a service in `services.yml`:

```
services
    app.helper:
        class: 'AppBundle\Helper\Helper'
```

and in your MyController:

```
public function someFunctionAction() {
    ...
    $helper = $this->get('app.helper');
    $something = $helper->getSomeHelp();
```